# AutoFormatting Lines in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, editor, formatter

I was using the formatter in IntelliJ and the right margin was `100`

Because of this, when I auto format my code: IntelliJ automatically split long statements which was intended.

```
return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(myEnum -> myEnum.getValue() == enumValue).findFirst()
      .orElse(SomeEnum.CUSTOM);
```

Now, I changed right margin to `160` and when i auto format it again it does not rollback the splitted statements into one statement such like following:

```
return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(myEnum -> myEnum.getValue() == enumValue).findFirst().orElse(SomeEnum.CUSTOM);
```

There are lots of codes in project and i do not want to do this process manually.

Are there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found solution.

```
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Keep when reformatting
```

Uncheck the `Line breaks` checkbox and reformat the code again.
It worked for my case.